# Discover if 32bit or 64bit Java is installed from a BAT file

Tags: java, registry, 32bit-64bit

In my BAT file I would like to have something like:

```
set javaVersion=...

if %javaVersion% equ 32 (
  echo "do 32 Java routine"
) else (
  echo "do non-32 Java routine"
)
```

On a 64bit machine, with JRE 64bit installed, in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6` I see almost the same values as on a 32bit machine with JRE 32bit installed:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
    CurrentVersion:       1.6
    Java6FamilyVersion:   1.6.0_26

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6
    JavaHome:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
    MicroVersion:         0
    RuntimeLib:           C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

Therefore, I could check if it is 64bit Java by checking if `PROGRAMFILES(X86)` is defined and if `JavaHome` points to location which starts with `C:\Program Files\`.

But is there a better option?

Comment: you might do a command line java -version and see which one runs by parsing the resulting string....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the output of `java -version` - it's in there.
Here's the output on my mac:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-10M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)
```

You should find either "64-Bit" or "32-Bit" in the output.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the 32-Bit Server does not output "32-Bit". On my system (32-bit Kubuntu), I get the following `java -version`output:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Therefore, it's a better idea to just test for absence of 64-Bit, instead of presence of either.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know if there is Java available then run a small class doing something with the default java command.

If you need to know which libraries to use, then instead of poking around the registry then run a small class which tries to call native code in your libraries and let the bat file know if it went well, and run it once for each of your supported platforms.

If none works, then report that.  If one or more works then choose the one you like best and use that.

In other words:  Explicitly test for what you need to know.  Any assumptions will eventually fail.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to parse the exit code of `java -d64 -version`.

For 64-bit JDK, it would be 0, for 32-bit: 1.

So, you may introduce new variable java64bit:

```
java -d64 -version >NUL 2>NUL
set java64bit=%ERRORLEVEL%
```